# How can I see the output of my travis build

Tags: node.js, testing, build, travis-ci

I can't get my tests to work when I build my node.js project using travis CI, **although they are working locally using "npm test"**.

My tests (only one) is defined in the package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt --verbose"
  },
```

And all I do in the .travis.yml file is:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"

script:
  - cd microservicebus.host && npm test
```

If I change it to below it works (but still no output)

```
script:
  - echo 'Hello'
```

If I could only get some useful output from the build, I could probably figure it out, but I all I can see is something like this:

```
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd microServiceBus/microservicebus.host
$ git checkout -qf 9ad3d17e94e6f4bacbc.....
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not al....
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
$ nvm install 0.10
##########################
```

Thankful for any suggestions

Comment: What can you see when you use test with the `echo` command?

Answer (score 0):

The complete error log that you are not seeing is probably:

> This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
>   If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml

Try disallowing sudo in your `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"

script:
  - cd microservicebus.host && npm test
```

You can get more info about Travis CI container based infraestructure here:
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/